# Model is not appearing in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I have been trying various options for all day to solve my problem. I was also trying various examples posted here in previous years. Although my problem is still unsolved and my objects are not appearing.

I was trying 3 different formats: .json, .js and now .mtl with.obj. My current code looks like this:

```
function addModels() {
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();

mtlLoader.load("../models/lampa.mtl", function (materials) {
    materials.preload();

    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

    objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
    objLoader.load("../models/lampa.obj", function (mesh) {
        mesh.scale.set(1,1,1);
        mesh.position.set(0,0,0);

        scene.add(mesh);
    })
})
```

And this is html file with the script running canvas.

```
   var camera;
var scene;
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var controls;

//Simple functions to initialise scene and render it.
initialise();
render();
//animate();


//add models
addModels();

function initialise() {

    // Create a scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // Add the camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(0, 100, 250);

    // Add scene elements
    addWalls();
    addKerbs();
    // Add lights
    addLights();
    // Create the WebGL Renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    //add Grass
    createGrass();
    addGrass();

    // Append the renderer to the body
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // Add a resize event listener
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', Resize, false );

    // Add the orbit controls
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 100, 0);
}

//rendering function
function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
    controls.update();
}

//Window resize.
function Resize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
    status.update();
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
}
```

When addModels() is in initialise function, but it throws an error like this:
 [image]

Every answer is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am really sorry for every trouble. It appears that everything is fine here, just three.js was out of date...